# How to fix the "The inserted Ring is not contained in a feature"?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, features

I am trying to add a ring in a feature in a shapefile. This feature is a single part feature but has already a few rings. When I try to add the new ring, I have the error message : "The inserted Ring is not contained in a feature". I tried to modify my snapping options thinking that the problem came from this setting, but I didn't have any luck.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem?

I use QGis 1.8.0-Lisboa and Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: are creating a inner ring or deleting from a single part polygon?

Comment: I am creating an inner ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new ring, if the ring outline intersect any of the existing rings, you would get that error message. Here i tried to create the red ring, but it is intersecting an existing ring. Also check if there are any unwanted snapping to edges setup.

[image]